# Product name on a pop up window

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, product-attribute

In my home page there is product listing. Each product contains a button called "Add to Cart". On clicking it is adding into the cart and a pop up is showing telling "your product has been added to the cart". I want to show the respective product name in the pop up .
Following is the ajax code while clicking on the button..

```
jQuery('#buy_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>').click(function() { 
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/index/add',
    dataType: 'json',
    type : 'post',
    data: { isAjax: 1, qty: 1, product: jQuery(this).data('product-id') },
    success: function(data){
        jQuery('#add-product-container').jqmShow();
    }
});

return false;
});
<div id="add-product-container" class="jqmWindow">
    <ul class="messages clearfix" id="add-product">
        <li class="success-msg">
            <span class="spnPrdname"><?php echo "PRODUCT NAME"; ?></span> 
            <span>has been added to <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart'); ?>" class="text-link">your basket</a>.</span>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return product name from ajax  contoller `IndexController.php` `addAction` function. Then Using JavaScript replace  `span#spnPrdname` content

***jQuery("span.spnPrdname").html(data);***

Comment: Unable to find the file url: '/ajax/index/add'. There is no module named "ajax" exists.. But products get added to cart. That means it is redirecting to some where. Can u please help me in this regard ?

Comment: this module router name.. You  can find any of your 3rd parlty extension

Comment: Yes . I found It . Now it is working .Thanks @Amit Bera

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean to replace `` with the proper product name.

That said:

`<?php echo "PRODUCT NAME"; ?>` should be `<?php echo $_product->getName() ?>`

Comment: But, I'm starting to wonder if you are repeating/iterating this script through every item on your homepage?

Comment: Every product tile in the page has a button called "Add to cart". On clicking it, the above code executes. I am getting the product_id and product_name before the button click. But don't know how to show it on that <?php echo "PRODUCT NAME"; ?>.